# ActiveAdmin Formtastic getting multi-select to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, multi-select, formtastic

I know how to make the multi-select form as stated in this documentation.
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/SelectInput

```
f.input :name, :as => :select, :collection => ["Justin", "Kate"]
```

It's not clear to me what I had to put inside the permit_params in order for this form request to go through.

I'm doing this through the Company model.
So I have

```
ActiveAdmin.register Company do
permit_params :name
controller do
    def create
      puts params
      company = Company.new(permitted_params[:company])
      if company.save
        redirect_to admin_companies_path
      else
        redirect_to new_admin_company_path, alert: 'Please fill all the fields'
      end
    end
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name, :as => :select, :collection => ["a","b","c"] 
    end
  end
end
```

When I submit a form with "b" and "c" selected, i see the following in params[:company]

```
"company"=>{"name"=>["", "b","c"]}, "commit"=>"Create Company", "controller"=>"admin/companies", "action"=>"create"}
Unpermitted parameter: name
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

It's not clear to me in the activeadmin, or formtastic documentation, what I need to change in permit_params in order to let this through.

By the way, as you can tell, this is a toy example. After I get this working, I would like to figure out how to do this for a **has_many** associations. If it's easier to figure out a solution via that path please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
permit_params name: []
```